# Java Thread Live Lock

Tags: multithreading, livelock

I have an interesting problem related to Java thread live lock. Here it goes.

There are four global locks - L1,L2,L3,L4

There are four threads - T1, T2, T3, T4

T1 requires locks L1,L2,L3
T2 requires locks L2
T3 required locks L3,L4
T4 requires locks L1,L2

So, the pattern of the problem is - Any of the threads can run and acquire the locks in any order. If any of the thread detects that a lock which it needs is not available, it release all other locks it had previously acquired waits for a fixed time before retrying again. The cycle repeats giving rise to a  live lock condition.

So, to solve this problem, I have two solutions in mind

1) Let each thread wait for a random period of time before retrying.

```
OR,
```

2) Let each thread acquire all the locks in a particular order ( even if a thread does not require all the
   locks)

I am not convinced that these are the only two options available to me. Please advise.

Comment: Indeed. (1) has avoidable latency and (2) has extreme deadlock potential, as highlighted by Zim-Zam, unless threads that fail to get their locks release the ones already aquired and retry later.

Answer (score 1):

Have all the threads enter a single mutex-protected state-machine whenever they require and release their set of locks. The threads should expose methods that return the set of locks they require to continue and also to signal/wait for a private semaphore signal.  The SM should contain a bool for each lock and a 'Waiting' queue/array/vector/list/whatever container to store waiting threads.

If a thread enters the SM mutex to get locks and can immediately get its lock set, it can reset its bool set, exit the mutex and continue on.

If a thread enters the SM mutex and cannot immediately get its lock set, it should add itself to 'Waiting',  exit the mutex and wait on its private semaphore.

If a thread enters the SM mutex to release its locks, it sets the lock bools to 'return' its locks and iterates 'Waiting' in an attempt to find a thread that can now run with the set of locks available. If it finds one, it resets the bools appropriately, removes the thread it found from 'Waiting' and signals the 'found' thread semaphore.  It then exits the mutex.

You can twiddle with the algorithm that you use to match up the available set lock bools with waiting threads as you wish.  Maybe you should release the thread that requires the largest set of matches, or perhaps you would like to 'rotate' the 'Waiting' container elements to reduce starvation.  Up to you.

A solution like this requires no polling, (with its performance-sapping CPU use and latency), and no continual aquire/release of multiple locks.

It's much easier to develop such a scheme with an OO design.  The methods/member functions to signal/wait the semaphore and return the set of locks needed can usually be stuffed somewhere in the thread class inheritance chain.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a good reason (performance wise) not to do so,
I would unify all locks to one lock object.
This is similar to solution 2 you suggested, only more simple in my opinion.

And by the way, not only is this solution more simple and less bug proned,
The performance might be better than solution 1 you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have never heard of Option 1, but I am by no means an expert on multithreading. After thinking about it, it sounds like it will work fine.

However, the standard way to deal with threads and resource locking is somewhat related to Option 2. To prevent deadlocks, resources need to always be acquired in the same order. For example, if you always lock the resources in the same order, you won't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Go with 2a) Let each thread acquire all of the locks that it needs (NOT all of the locks) in a particular order; if a thread encounters a lock that isn't available then it releases all of its locks

As long as threads acquire their locks in the same order you can't have deadlock; however, you can still have starvation (a thread might run into a situation where it keeps releasing all of its locks without making forward progress).  To ensure that progress is made you can assign priorities to threads (0 = lowest priority, MAX_INT = highest priority) - increase a thread's priority when it has to release its locks, and reduce it to 0 when it acquires all of its locks.  Put your waiting threads in a queue, and don't start a lower-priority thread if it needs the same resources as a higher-priority thread - this way you guarantee that the higher-priority threads will eventually acquire all of their locks.  Don't implement this thread queue unless you're actually having problems with thread starvation, though, because it's probably less efficient than just letting all of your threads run at once.

You can also simplify things by implementing omer schleifer's condense-all-locks-to-one solution; however, unless threads other than the four you've mentioned are contending for these resources (in which case you'll still need to lock the resources from the external threads), you can more efficiently implement this by removing all locks and putting your threads in a circular queue (so your threads just keep running in the same order).